# Export sklearn model to run in R

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn

I've built a random forest model using sklearn in Python. How can I export the model object `irisfit` so that it can be read in R and used to make predictions there?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
iris = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
features = iris[['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width']]
target = iris['class']
irisfit = RandomForestClassifier().fit(features, target)
```

Comment: In general, you don’t.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if is possible to export a  sklearn learn model to R, you can try two options to solve your problem.

First, try the library reticulate. With reticulate you can sourcing Python scripts in R. (https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)

Another option is deploying your ML model as a REST API using Flask RESTful and call it from R using GET from httr library.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interchange between R and Python for a model. A model deployed in Python will be used in Python. If you want to use an RF in R then why build it in Python? Iris data is also available in R.

I think if you use XGBoost then it can be transferred from Python to R and vice versa but I've never tried it.

Comment: Iris is just an example. In reality I work at a place where developers have built models in both R and Python, and now we're trying to integrate them.

Comment: The scripts remain the same.